# Access sql query based on user provided date only returns dates with times = 0:00:00

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, prompt

Haven't found any closely related questions, so here goes.

This is a simple version of my query:

```
SELECT sampleID, beginDateTime
FROM sample
WHERE DateValue(beginDateTime) = [Enter sample date: ];
```

This returns no records but should return 3 based on the date I entered.

However, this version returns what I expect, all the records that match the supplied date and their respective times.

```
SELECT sampleID, beginDateTime
FROM sample
WHERE DateValue(beginDateTime) = #2015-5-18#;
```

How can I enable a user prompt that is properly formatted in Access SQL that will return the appropriate records? Note: I don't know VBA.

Also tried adding `PARAMETER = beginDateTime DateTime;` This seems to return all records and assigns them all the date that the user was prompted for.

Tried using DateValue in the parameter list:

```
SELECT sampleID, DateValue(beginDateTime)
FROM sample
WHERE beginDateTime = [Enter sample date: ];
```

This only returns dates = 0:00:00

I'd like my query to prompt the user for a date (without a time) and return all records with that date along with their respective times.

I would appreciate your help very much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the parameter using the correct syntax:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter sample date: ] DateTime;
SELECT sampleID, beginDateTime
FROM sample
WHERE DateValue(beginDateTime) = [Enter sample date: ];
```

Then it will accept a date entered as to the format of your current Windows settings.

Comment: +1 for suggestion to use a typed parameter.  Not so great idea: filtering on an expression if very inefficient.

Comment: So the suggestions that use PARAMETER and also include a user prompt return in prompting the user twice.

Comment: We have only your query, not how and where you use. The parameter will be prompted for once only.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Gustav's suggestion to use a typed parameter (which has the added benefit that Access will refuse a non valid date):

```
PARAMETER [Enter sample date: ] DateTime;
SELECT sampleID, beginDateTime
FROM sample
WHERE beginDateTime >= [Enter sample date: ] and beginDateTime < ([Enter sample date: ]+1)
```

This way you avoid filtering on an expression, which disables index usage, and therefore would be slow on large datasets.

---

**Edit:** To achieve this in the interface, just open your query in design view, then go to Design, Parameters, and enter the name and data type of your parameter(s).

Comment: @Abby, Parameterized queries are safer than using string concatenation, because string concatenation is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. SQL Injection is only a real concern if your database is publicly available. Since you were using an input box already, I just fixed your example. It is no more risky than what you had in place. It is a good habit to use parameterized queries, but not always absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Abby: at the simplest level, the user can make a typo and enter a "non date" value, and then your `CDate` will fail. By defining your parameter as a date, any 'non date' will be refused. Not to mention the query will run faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the value coming back from the input box to a date:

```
SELECT sampleID, beginDateTime
  FROM sample
 WHERE DateValue(beginDateTime) = CDate([Enter sample date: ]);
```

Comment: Tht's risky and for less efficient compared to @Gustav's answer

Comment: Thanks, StoneGiant. Is there a way to incorporate this syntax into a query that's called by a form? Or is this off topic? I tried DateValue([sample.beginDateTime])=([Forms]![Lab Replicate Query Form]![date_time]) in the sql query. And added to the form that I want to run the query, in Control Source = CDate([beginDateTime]) but not luck. Any suggestions? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that would be a new question with more details about what you're doing.